# Nested Function in Python

Tags: python, nested-function

What benefit or implications could we get with Python code like this:

```py
class some_class(parent_class):
    def doOp(self, x, y):
        def add(x, y):
            return x + y
        return add(x, y)
```

I found this in an open-source project, doing something useful inside the nested function, but doing absolutely nothing outside it except calling it. (The actual code can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eopenerp/openobject-server/trunk/annotate/1861/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py#L685).) Why might someone code it like this? Is there some benefit or side effect for writing the code inside the nested function rather than in the outer, normal function?

Comment: Is this the actual code you found, or just a simplified example you constructed?

Comment: It's a simplified example. The actual code can be found here: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eopenerp/openobject-server/trunk/annotate/head%3A/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py#L685

Comment: Your link (which points to HEAD) is now not accurate. Try: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/annotate/1861/bin/report/render/rml2pdf/trml2pdf.py#L685

Comment: You're right Craig. Thank you.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Normally you do it to make *[closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)*:

```
def make_adder(x):
    def add(y):
        return x + y
    return add

plus5 = make_adder(5)
print(plus5(12))  # prints 17
```

Inner functions can access variables from the enclosing scope (in this case, the local variable `x`).  If you're not accessing any variables from the enclosing scope, they're really just ordinary functions with a different scope.

Comment: For that I'd prefer partials: `plus5 = functools.partial(operator.add, 5)`. Decorators would be a better example for closures.

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see in the snippet I posted, that's not the case here: the nested function is simply being called in the outer function.

Answer (score 63):

Aside from function generators, where internal function creation is almost the definition of a function generator, the reason I create nested functions is to improve readability.  If I have a tiny function that will only be invoked by the outer function, then I inline the definition so you don't have to skip around to determine what that function is doing.  I can always move the inner method outside of the encapsulating method if I find a need to reuse the function at a later date.

Toy example:

```
import sys

def Foo():
    def e(s):
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: ')
        sys.stderr.write(s)
        sys.stderr.write('\n')
    e('I regret to inform you')
    e('that a shameful thing has happened.')
    e('Thus, I must issue this desultory message')
    e('across numerous lines.')
Foo()
```

Comment: The only problem is that this can sometimes make it harder to unit test, because you can't access the inner function.

Comment: They look so lovely!

Comment: FWIY @Challenger5 if the inner function is analogous to private class functions they aren't unit-tested anyway. I have started doing this to make methods more readable while keeping the definition close to the method in question.

Answer (score 27):

One potential benefit of using inner methods is that it allows you to use outer method local variables without passing them as arguments.

```
def helper(feature, resultBuffer):
  resultBuffer.print(feature)
  resultBuffer.printLine()
  resultBuffer.flush()

def save(item, resultBuffer):

  helper(item.description, resultBuffer)
  helper(item.size, resultBuffer)
  helper(item.type, resultBuffer)
```

can be written as follows, which arguably reads better

```
def save(item, resultBuffer):

  def helper(feature):
    resultBuffer.print(feature)
    resultBuffer.printLine()
    resultBuffer.flush()

  helper(item.description)
  helper(item.size)
  helper(item.type)
```

Answer (score 8):

I can't image any good reason for code like that.

Maybe there was a reason for the inner function in older revisions, like other Ops.

For example, this makes *slightly* more sense:

```
class some_class(parent_class):
    def doOp(self, op, x, y):
        def add(x, y):
            return x + y
        def sub(x,y):
            return x - y
        return locals()[op](x,y)

some_class().doOp('add', 1,2)
```

but then the inner function should be ("private") class methods instead:

```
class some_class(object):
    def _add(self, x, y):
        return x + y
    def doOp(self, x, y):
        return self._add(x,y)
```

Comment: Yeah, maybe doOp took a string to specify which operator to use on the arguments...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare it's preferred to simply use modules. Classes are for state.

Answer (score 6):

The idea behind local methods is similar to local variables: don't pollute the larger name space.  Obviously the benefits are limited since most languages don't also provide such functionality directly.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the code was exactly like this? The normal reason for doing something like this is for creating a partial - a function with baked-in parameters. Calling the outer function returns a callable that needs no parameters, and so therefore can be stored and used somewhere it is impossible to pass parameters. However, the code you've posted won't do that - it calls the function immediately and returns the result, rather than the callable. It might be useful to post the actual code you saw.

Comment: I've added a link to the original code in a comment on my question. As you can see, mine is a simplified example, but it's still almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use a nested function to create **a decorator** like `@decorator`. *[**My answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046883/what-is-decorator-with-above-a-function-in-python/74415767#74415767) explains more about decorators.

I created `multiply_by_5()` to use it as the decorator for `sum()` as shown below:

```py
# (4 + 6) x 5 = 50

def multiply_by_5(func):
    def core(*args, **kwargs):
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result * 5
    return core

@multiply_by_5 # Here
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

result = sum(4, 6)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
50
```

The code below is the case of not using the decorator:

```py
# (4 + 6) x 5 = 50

# ...

# @multiply_by_5
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

f1 = multiply_by_5(sum) # Here
result = f1(4, 6)
print(result)
```

Or:

```py
# (4 + 6) x 5 = 50

# ...

# @multiply_by_5
def sum(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

result = multiply_by_5(sum)(4, 6) # Here
print(result)
```

Output:

```
50
```