# fill() in pygame.display.set_mode().fill((0, 200, 255))

Tags: python, function, pygame

Consider this line in the pygame loop:

```
pygame.display.set_mode().fill((0, 200, 255))
```

From: http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html

I. How are you supposed to know there even is a fill function nested in set_mode? I searched in the pygame documentation and there is no information on fill in the set_mode section.

II. `set_mode()` is a function of the display module of the pygame package. How can I call a function nested in another function?
How could I call `print"hi"` with this function(tried it but get an AttributeError):

```
def f():
    def g():
        print "hi"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pygame.display.set_mode() returns a Surface object.

From the [documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode):

> pygame.display.set_mode initialize a window or screen for display
>   pygame.display.set_mode(resolution=(0,0), flags=0, depth=0): return Surface

So you are calling the method `.fill()` on the surface object, not on the function `set_mode()`.

You can find the methods available on surface objects in the [surface documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) of pygame.

You cannot call a nested function in that way. 
To get your desired result in your print example, you can use classes in the following way:

```
class F():
  def g(self):
    print "hi"
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> F().g()
hi
```

This is a simplified example to show how the `display.set_mode().fill()` works:

```
class Surface():
    def fill(self):
        print "filling"

class Display():
    def set_mode(self):
        return Surface()


Display().set_mode().fill()
```

Edit:

You can use nested functions, but it works slightly different from how you would do it with objects and modules:

```
def f():
  def g():
    print "hi"
  return g
```

Resulting in:

```
>>> outerf = f()
>>> outerf()
hi
```

Comment: For I. : Your example is different mainly because there `Display` is a class while in pygame it is a module. I think I get it. Thank you!! Now I also understand why display.set_mode() is stored into a variable first.



So for II.: You are saying you simply cannot call a function nested in another function.

Comment: You can call a function nested in another function. It is done slightly different though. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589058/nested-function-in-python
Edit: You're right about display being a module.

Comment: Thnx. But I can't find how to call the nested fucntion though. In your link somebody points out you can do this(applied to my example):

     `outerf = f()` then
     `outerf()`

But this doesn't work.

Comment: Btw: I forgot to add the `def` keyword in the nested function in my original post. I changed it.

Comment: @Bentley4 I updated the answer with an example of a nested function.