# calling a function inside another function(nested)

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures, nested-function

I have a function in Python

```
def outer_function():
    def inner_funtion():
        print ('inner message')
    print('outer message')
    sys.exit()
```

How do I call the inner function? I'm quite new to the inspect library and with closure if this qualifies as closure.

Comment: You call it the same way you call any other function... `inner_funtion()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589058/nested-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You call it as any other function `inner_funtion()` but it's accessible only in `outer_function` scope obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `inner_function()` anywhere in the scope where `inner_function()` is defined, that is anywhere in `outer_function()` after you defined `inner_function()`.

Answer (score 0):

I find myself using this technique quite a bit.
As one of the commenters wrote, you just call it:

```
def outer_function():
    def inner_funtion():
        print ('inner message')
    print('outer message')
    inner_function()
    sys.exit()

>>> outer_function()
outer message
inner message
```

This only works within the scope of `outer_function()`, and will return an error if you try to call `inner_function()` anywhere but inside `outer_function()`.

Using nested functions are a great technique to clean up otherwise unwieldy top-level functions.

As for your second question, [the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020419/why-arent-python-nested-functions-called-closures?rq=1) does a better job than I ever could.