# What is the Syntactical Function of Nested Defintion in Python?

Tags: python, nested, definition

Following is a model given by a module.

If you look inside of it, you can check two definitin of functions are defined in a nested depth.

I've never seen this before.

How's it working?

```
def load(filepath, shape_only=False):
  def readpca(f, nv):
    nc,nd  = struct.unpack('<II', f.read(8))
    assert(nd == 3*nv)
    funcs  = [[struct.unpack('<d', f.read(8))[0] for d in range(nd)]
              for c in range(nc)]
    (nm,)  = struct.unpack('<I', f.read(4))
    assert(nm == 3*nv)
    # fyi: elements are ordered x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,...xnv,ynv,znv.
    vmean  = [struct.unpack('<d', f.read(8))[0] for i in range(nm)]
    (ne,)  = struct.unpack('<I', f.read(4))
    values = [struct.unpack('<d', f.read(8))[0] for i in range(ne)]
    return PCAModel(vmean, funcs, values)

  with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
    nv,nt = struct.unpack('<II', f.read(8))
    # fyi: faces is a list of tuples (each tuple contains 3 vertex indices).
    faces = [struct.unpack('<III', f.read(12)) for i in range(nt)]
    shape = readpca(f, nv)
    try:
      textr = None if shape_only else readpca(f, nv)
    except Exception:
      print('No texture data. Returning shape-only model.')
      textr = None

  return MorphModel(faces, shape, textr)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested Function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589058/nested-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

The function definition in Python:

```
def foo():
    pass
```

and a variable assignment:

```
foo = 17
```

are completely identical, except one binds to a variable (`foo`) a function value, and the other, a non-function value (and the fact that Python chose to make them wildly dissimilar, syntactically).

So let's see, what would be the difference between the following two?

```
foo = 17
def bar():
    print(foo)

def bar():
    foo = 17
    print(foo)
```

In the first one, the scope of the variable `foo` is wider than the function `bar`; in the second one, `foo` is local to `bar`.

Almost exactly the same thing in your case. The `load` function needs a helper function `readpca`, but it is not interested in having it available outside `load`, so it defines it as local to the function.

Actually, with functions it is a bit more complex because of the concept of closure: the tl;dr is that a function will have access to variables of the environment it is defined in. It is not used here at all, but `readpca` would have access to the variables `filepath` and `readonly`, if it wanted to; if `readpca` was defined outside `load`, those would have to be passed via extra parameters, if `readpca` were interested in them. This closure effect is another reason a function might want to be defined inside another function.