# stacked functions / one in another

Tags: python, function

I am a fresh beginner in learning Python, and need some hints to understand the following exercise :

the goal is to write a script that uses the **cube function** in the calculus of the **volume of a sphere.**

Also please don't mind my grammar errors as English is not my first language. Thank you !

```
r = float(input("choose a number :"))

def volume_sphere(cube(r)):

    pi = 3.14
    cube = int(r**3)
    return(cube)

  volume_sphere = float(4/3*pi*cube(r))
  return(volume_sphere)

volume_sphere(r)

#volume_sphere = volume_sphere(cube(r))
```

Is this possible to do ? This is how I understand the relationship between both functions

print("the volume of the sphere is : , volume_sphere(r)")

Comment: Also please tell me how you modify the lines so it appears as code in a post :/

Comment: If you indent the code lines by 4 spaces, it will format as code.

Comment: okay thank you !! will do that for the future

Answer (score 0):

You would define two separate functions, and then one function can call the other. In this case `volume_sphere` can call `cube`.

```
import math

def cube(x):
    return x**3

def volume_sphere(r):
    return math.pi * cube(r)
```

Then you would just call this like

```
radius = float(input("choose a number :"))
volume = volume_sphere(radius)
print("the volume of the sphere is : {}".format(volume))
```

Note that you are free to define a function within another function.

```
def volume_sphere(r):
    def cube(x):
        return x**3
    return math.pi * cube(r)
```

In this particular case I don't see a strong reason to do so. These are [typically used for closures or wrappers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589058/nested-function-in-python).

Comment: okay thank you !! So putting a function in another one is impossible, right ? Like that : def volume_sphere(cube(r)):

Comment: @KokoKara I've edited my answer. You *can* define a nested function, though in this specific case I don't think you *should*.

Comment: all right, thank you. Lastly, is calling a function the same as saying "return" ?