# Make a function inside of another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if you can make a function inside of another function in python. Just like this:

```
f().f2()
```

The `f()` is the first function, and `f2()` is the second function. Say `f().f2()` prints out `"Hello world"`. But if I change the `.f2()` to `.f3()` it will print another string of text.

Is it possible?

Comment: You might want to check [classes](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp).

Comment: Yes, you just have to return an object from f that has callable f2 and f3 attributes.

Comment: @RiveN I am not talking about classes, i am talking about how to add a function inside of another function.

Comment: But why? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rydex You might want to take a look into inner functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1589606/4224925).

Comment: I am trying to understand what you mean when you say "add a function inside of another function". Could you please elaborate.

Comment: Perhaps a module is what you are after https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
def f():
    class F:
        @staticmethod
        def f2():
            print("Hello world")

        @staticmethod
        def f3():
            print("Another string of text")
    return F


f().f2()
f().f3()
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But I think we should question OPs rational as it feels like an XY problem.

Comment: Wonderful! the benefit of doing this is that your IDE can offer auto-completion hints apparently.

Comment: @rv.kvetch And the downside is that `F` will be redefined every single time `f` is called, which can have a high overhead

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good, but a simpler solution would be to make `f` a class. Since classes are callable, you can basically treat them as functions. The dot in `f().f2()` implies that `f` must return an object with an `f2` attribute, and a class can do just that:

```
class f:

    def f2(self):
        print("Hello world")

    def f3(self):
        print('another string of text')
```

Answer (score 1):

I like [Samwise answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69617357/10237506) better, but here's a way of doing it without classes, if you really wanted to:

```py
def f():
    def f2():
        print("Hello world")

    def f3():
        print("Another string of text")

    for func_name, func in locals().items():
        setattr(f, func_name, func)

    return f


f().f2()
f().f3()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f():
    class F:
        @staticmethod
        def f_2():
            print("something")

        @staticmethod
        def f_3():
            print("something 2")
    return F


f().f_2()
f().f_3()
```